# First or Zero conditional? Setence-usage

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-usage, conditionals

I know that:

> 0 Condition - For facts that always happen;

Whereas:

> 1st Conditional - For specific facts;

So, why People use Zero conditional in these sentences, even though is a one-time thing?

> If I find lava in this game, this video ends (even though is just this time that  I am going to end this video if I find lava)
>
> If you are reading this, I'm at the library by now (That does not mean that I will always find you at the library if I read this)
>
> If you read this, you're strange (that doesn't mean I'll always be strange if I read this)

Please, correct if I'm wrong

I thank you in advance

Comment: The categorization of conditionals is not something done by most native speakers. It's a generalization that is often incomplete or confusing (mostly only provided by ESL teachers and texts), and it's certainly not a strict rule. It serves only as a guidepost.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but, How can I learn the Conditionals types?

Comment: What I'm saying is that those categories are too limiting. There are actually a vast number of conditionals—far more than just the standard four that seem to be typically described. It's also mostly futile to try to list all of them in a useful way. For any native speaker, asking about an Xth conditional doesn't really convey much. As much as I understand the definitions, these sentences are either actually 1st conditionals, or ambiguously a combination of the 0 and 1st, depending on your interpretation.